# ER diagram modeling of a auction transaction

Tags: database-design, relational-database, entity-relationship

I'm studying ER diagrams, and I'm still confused on some aspects of it.

I'm doing an exercise, and I came up with two solutions that i think might work, but I'm not sure which one would be the correct one and what would be the resulting differences between them.

The problem I'm trying to model is an online auction system, with members that can be buyers and sellers ( they have common attributes like mail address, name, and password). The seller also has an attribute bank account, and the buyer has an attribute shipping address. So I've drawn it as a disjoint generalization.

A seller can sell an item, and a buyer can bid for an item.

an item has a category, which can have a subcategory.

the doubt I'm facing is now here:
at the end of the auction, the bidder with the highest bid is a winner, and a transaction between the seller and the buyer may proceed. the Buyer and the seller also can record a feedback( rating + comment) on the transaction.

My two approaches for the transaction are the following:

**Solution 1**
[image: Solution 1]

Making the transaction as a three way relationship between buyer,seller and item, and adding the feedback attribute to the relationship

**Solution 2**
[image: Solution 2]

Insert directly the feedback and the winner ID in the item. ( Can't sell more items with a single listing)

Thank you in advance for the help

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use an image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text. And never give a diagram without a legend/key.

Comment: PS You were wondering. But what exactly is your question?

Comment: I was basically trying to resolve [this](https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/consider-onlineauction-database-system-members-buyers-sellers-participate-sale-items-data--q16320905) problem, and got stuck for quite some time on the last two points, and made many different designs, the two i posted were the one i thought had more sense.

Comment: Please clarify via integrated post edits, not comments. PS Standard grammar please. PS "Basically" not in the context of clear full precise details it is introducing or summarizing basically says nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say exactly how to populate the entity & relationship sets/tables. You haven't actually given a design until you do that. Making reasonable assumptions about that & constraints, it seems that both these designs can record your situations. For 2 to work requires (something like) that the domain of Winner_ID is the domain of buyer ids plus some value that cannot be a buyer id. SQL typically uses NULL for that sort of sentinel value.

```
-- "I ids an item"
Item_1(I)
-- "buyer B makes a transaction with seller S for item I with feedback F"
MakesATransaction_1(B, S, I, F)

-- "item I has either winner B & feedback F or no winner & B is null & F is null"
Item_2(I, B, F)
```

You can see they can record the same situations because for all B, I & F, [for some S, "buyer B makes a transaction with seller S for item I with feedback F"] in 1 if and only if ["item I has either winner B & feedback F or no winner & B is null & F is null" & B is null & F is null] in 2. This also means that each entity/relationship table in one design can be expressed as a query in the other. Key to this equivalence are cardinalities like that transactions are 1:1 with items with winners.

PS In 2 instead of storing winner id you could just store whether there is a winner/transaction. Do you see why? (A: You can query for the winner.)

(Pin down the membership criteria (*(characteristic) predicates*) of your relationships/tables. Explore how you would query & constrain each design. Also explore how what changes/extensions are likely favour one over the other.)

PS "Has" means nothing. Pick relationship names descriptive of how the participating entities *are related*. Best is, shorthand for a clear statement template that makes a statement when given is/values for entities/attributes. "item I is a member of category C".

PS Why arrows? They are redundant.

Comment: Thank you so much for all the good comments, just started and have many doubts about it. I will work on it to fix everything. I mostly want to get the concept as I always tend to make extra entities in the diagram.

Comment: Re finding relationships, find *predicates*--statement templates parameterized by columns by which the database states about the situation. (Rows in tables state truths, absent rows state falsehoods.) Find sufficient ones to describe your situations. When some are expressible via combinations of others (which depends partly on constraints) keep just some. See my answers re database design & table predicates. Best ER method is Object-Role Modeling. Except ER makes unnecessary & limiting distinctions between entities & relationships. The relational model is just n-ary relationships.